# How to prevent FileNotFoundException in GetAllNetworkInterfaces() when called in AWS Lambda .net environment?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, lambda

**Problem**

The method `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` throws a `FileNotFoundException` if executed in an AWS Lambda environment.

**Analysis**

This function:

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

[assembly: Amazon.Lambda.Core.LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace CheckerLambda
{
    public class Function
    {
        public string FunctionHandler(Amazon.Lambda.Core.ILambdaContext context)
        {
            // Here we get an "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/sys/class/net/lo/mtu'."
            var adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

            // do something with 'adapters'

            return "This point is never reached";
        }
    }
}
```

Leads to this exception if executed in an AWS Lambda environment.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/sys/class/net/lo/mtu'.
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at Interop.CheckIo[TSafeHandle](TSafeHandle handle, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at System.IO.UnixFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, FileStream parent)
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at System.IO.UnixFileSystem.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, FileStream parent)
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding)
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at System.Net.NetworkInformation.StringParsingHelpers.ParseRawIntFile(String filePath)
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at System.Net.NetworkInformation.LinuxIPv4InterfaceProperties..ctor(LinuxNetworkInterface linuxNetworkInterface)
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at System.Net.NetworkInformation.LinuxIPInterfaceProperties..ctor(LinuxNetworkInterface lni)
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at System.Net.NetworkInformation.LinuxNetworkInterface..ctor(String name)
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at System.Net.NetworkInformation.LinuxNetworkInterface.GetOrCreate(Dictionary`2 interfaces, String name)
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at System.Net.NetworkInformation.LinuxNetworkInterface.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GetLinuxNetworkInterfaces>b__2(String name, LinkLayerAddressInfo* llAddr)
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at Interop.Sys.EnumerateInterfaceAddresses(IPv4AddressDiscoveredCallback ipv4Found, IPv6AddressDiscoveredCallback ipv6Found, LinkLayerAddressDiscoveredCallback linkLayerFound)
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at System.Net.NetworkInformation.LinuxNetworkInterface.GetLinuxNetworkInterfaces()
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at CheckerLambda.Function.FunctionHandler(ILambdaContext context)
2017-47-04 15:47:21:    at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , ContextInfo )
```

Any idea what to do?

Comment: Put a try round it?

Comment: If I got the context your code is running in correct, you want to read all networkinterfaces in the AWS cloud, for what exactly?

Comment: Actually this line of code is included in a third party library which i want to use. It throws an exception when initializing it and I was able to trace down the source of the exception to this exact call.

The context is that I us a high level library to query a DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a known bug and will be fixed with .net core 2.0: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24422#issuecomment-334190332